# Interpreting SUMIf in excel sql

Tags: sql, excel, formulas

I have this SUMIF `=SUMIF(WEZ_ARTICLE_PLANT!A:A,$E2,WEZ_ARTICLE_PLANT!AX:AX)`
I want do the same as the sumif in sql excel.

In my query

```
WEZ_ARTICLE_PLANT!A:A = column_Material
$E2 = column_Material
WEZ_ARTICLE_PLANT!AX:AX = column_StockQty
```

I would be glad for any Responce!

Comment: I can't quite understand what you mean. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I want interpret the sumif formula in to SQL

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I am super sutpid I solved it...I was all the time doing it right but with newer file and this file has got different number...Thnak you for the help anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to start thinking of things in a slightly different way now that you are working with a database.

```
SELECT column_Material, SUM(column_StockQuantity)
  FROM YouTableName 
  GROUP BY column_Material
```

will give you a total of all quantities for each *column_Material*

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
Select sum(column_StockQty) from table_Name where column_Material = 'Example'
```

Comment: you need a `group by` as well I think.

Comment: Not in SQL Server if it's just the sum without any other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean a case statement?

```
Sum (CASE WHEN <SOME CRITERIA> then <YOUR COLUMN> else <NULL or SOME OTHER COLUMN> END) AS ...
```